# How can I only change the fields attribute in inherited serializer class in DRF?

Tags: python-3.x, django, api, class, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer as:-

```py
class SuperUserListSerializer(serializers.Modelserializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'phone_number',
            'birth_date',
            'is_active',
            'is_staff',
            'is_superuser',
            'groups',
        )
```

I want to remove some of the fields from this serializers, so what I did, rewrote the Meta class and gave the serializer appropriate required fields:-

```py
class UserListSerializer(SuperUserListSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'phone_number',
            'birth_date',
            'is_active',
            'groups',
        )
```

I am not satisfied by this approach, Is there any way I can do, so that I am not required to re-introduce the Meta class, and pass/change the appropriate fields for the second serializer

Answer (score 4):

If you want to inherit `SuperUserListSerializer`, you can do as following:

1. Subtract fields:

```py
class UserListSerializer(SuperUserListSerializer):
    class Meta(SuperUserListSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = tuple(set(SuperUserListSerializer.Meta.fields) - set(['is_staff', 'is_superuser']))
```

2. Add fields:

```py
class UserListSerializer(SuperUserListSerializer):
    class Meta(SuperUserListSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = SuperUserListSerializer.Meta.fields + ("new_field", )
```

But, if you don't want to inherit `SuperUserListSerializer`, do the following:

```py
common_fields = (
            'id',
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'phone_number',
            'birth_date',
            'is_active',
            'groups',
        )

class SuperUserListSerializer(serializers.Modelserializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = common_fields + ('is_staff', 'is_superuser')

class UserListSerializer(serializers.Modelserializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = common_fields
```

Comment: Still, we are required to introduced, the Meta class, I was thinking If this can be done without it

Comment: If you inherit `SuperUserListSerializer` and want to change `fields`, you must need to inherit `Meta` of parent class, because, `Meta` itself a class.